# How can I run .exe files in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, files, executable

I have lots of windows programs in .exe because i've changed windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. Help please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

install wine:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

Comment: `sudo apt install wine-stable`

Comment: Giving me error. `E: Unable to locate package wine-stable`

Comment: Updated instructions are at the official wine site: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu